# Flutter Engine Custom Embedder Platform Messages Not Working

Tags: c++, flutter, dart

I have successfully embedded Flutter in my OpenGL app using software renderer, using the official 2.0.1 build (using official artifacts from [the wiki page](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Custom-Flutter-Engine-Embedders). My project is similar to https://github.com/jwinarske/flutter_wayland for your reference.

Rendering & mouse/pointer events works fine. However, I'm not able to send or receive any platform messages to/from the flutter engine:

- The `FlutterProjectArgs.platform_message_callback` is never called, and
- sending keyboard events via `flutter/keyevent` has no effect (I implement something similar to the [glfw key handler](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/master/shell/platform/glfw/key_event_handler.cc)).
- Also if I use a native plugin, and if I invoke `MethodChannel` from Flutter/Dart side, it never returns (the native plugin works if we build the flutter app for desktop, for example Windows)).

For the project args, I only filled `assets_path`, `icu_data_path` & `platform_message_callback`, and the rest I leave to the default values.

Are there other prerequisites for communication with flutter using platform messages?

Thanks!

Comment: With the help of @stuartmorgan here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33521#issuecomment-801825040, the first issue is solved. I didn't service flutter engine with custom task runners. Still trying to figure out the second issue, `flutter/keyevent` event is not yet working.

Comment: As it turns out, the `flutter/keyevent` message has always worked, this is confirmed by using RawKeyboardListener on the Flutter side. Text input however as it turns out works quite differently. To make `TextField` to work, for example, one needs to also handle the `flutter/textinput` channel messages. I'll post an answer to my own question when I have it working.

Comment: could you please post an elaborate answer on your question? it would be very helpful.